# How can you transfer big files between Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

So I can transfer them via SFTP because windows has openSSH server pre-installed, but it's very slow. I want to transfer an 8GB+ machine so I can't do it via a USB neither because FAT32 can't handle. I need something fast.

Comment: How about Windows shares, a.k.a. SMB? First install Samba on Ubuntu.  Either configure shares on Ubuntu and pull the files from Windows, or share a directory on Windows and use `smbfs` or `smbclient` on Ubuntu to push them to the shared Windows directory. In my experience, it's very fast, 50 to 100 MBytes/s on a 1G LAN.

Comment: Wich protocol does SMB use to transfer the files?

Comment: SMB **is** the protocol. It stands for Server Message Block.

Comment: you should try `rsync` instead of sftp/scp